# Calculate the dynamics of ZCB given forward-rate dynamics

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-pde

Suppose the forward rate is given by:

$$df(t,u)= \frac{\partial}{\partial u} \bigg( \frac{\sigma(t,u)^2}{2} \bigg)dt
- \frac{\partial}{\partial u} \big( \sigma(t,u) \big)dW_t$$
where $W_t$ is a standard Brownian motion.

How do I find the dynamics of a zero coupon bond  $ \ p(t,T)$?

I know that $p(t,T)= e^{-\int_t^Tf(t,s)ds}$

I was thinking of using the ito formula on $f(x,t)=e^{-x}$ (plugging in $\int_t^Tf(t,s)ds$ for $x$) but I don't know how to compute the differential of
$\int_t^Tf(t,s)ds$. Any help is much appreciated!